# Homebrew cellar doesn't seem to exist

Tags: osx-mavericks, homebrew

I've been using `homebrew` for a while on OSX Mavericks, however I'm now dealing with needing to add files to folders of those same installed programs.

Here's the issue, when typing:

```
$ brew info ant
```

I get `/usr/local/Cellar/ant....`, as does any of my installed programs. The issue is that the `Cellar` doesn't seem to exist on my computer. When I search from `Spotlight` it finds no `usr` folder, with the exception of some nested within my Eclipse folder that hasn't been used for years. When I attempt to:

```
$ cd ~/usr/
```

it, too, doesn't exist. Also NO folder on my computer exists called `Cellar` (that `Spotlight` can find)

Does `homebrew` store this folder in some hidden way? (I'm hesitant to think this is the case, since I have all hidden files shown)

Comment: Worth noting:   You are correct that it is hidden in some way.  By default the usr folder is hidden along with all of its contents.  You can toggle this on/off by pressing "Shift+Command+Dot" on mac.  You will see the usr folder in your Macintosh HD root folder, and can dive in from there.  REMEMBER TO TOGGLE HIDDEN FILE VIEW OFF AFTER!  You dont want to accidentally leave it on and delete an important file.

Comment: Note that `/usr` is completely different from `~/usr`. The former is located at the root of your filesystem, denoted `/`, whereas the former is located in your home directly, denoted, `~/` which is usually shorthand for `/Users/<your-username/`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While in the `Finder`, enter <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and enter `/usr/local/Cellar` in the dialog that pops up.

Alternately, in `Terminal.app` (or whatever terminal program you're using), enter `open /usr/local/Cellar` at a prompt.

Both will open up a new `Finder` window to the `homebrew` `Cellar` directory.

You can verify that the `Cellar` directory is in the default location with `brew --cellar` in the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I found my Cellar folder on:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar
```

But the best trick is run the command `brew --cellar`

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing the homebrew solved the issue for me.

It looks like the issue after upgrading to Mavericks.

See https://brew.sh/ run the install again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type

```
cd /usr
```

not

```
cd ~/usr
```

/usr is at the top of the file directory for unix based systems, its not something in your home folder (~ = /Users/yourname )

to get spotlight to see the folder you will have to make a symlink to it somewhere outside of /usr.

This post covers a similar problem and has a suggested solution using Automomator to prevent any issues with any apps installed with homebrew: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23653/can-i-make-a-symlink-to-a-app-folder-in-applications-directory-show-up-in-spo